# how to set value on one of column on excel from other sheet column on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheet of excel one it is sheet for products

with have column like this

| id | name | barcode | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | opel blazer | 1239423 | europe car |
| 2 | toyota alphard | 9239239112 | japan car |
| 3 | Jeep | 90232321 | Jeep |

this sheet has 1000item and barcode

and other it is sheet for inventory

| id | product_id | barcode | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ???? | 9239239112 | 40 |
| 2 | ???? | 90232321 | 20 |

my question is how to set product_id at my inventory from id column from product sheet if we just has information for barcode ? so it will be use filtering and set by barcode

Comment: How you will set `product_id`? You do not have any `product_id` info to products sheet. You need `index/match` or xlookup function.

Comment: product_id it is id from my product sheet

Comment: i have mention it product_id at my inventory it is from id column on my product sheet

Comment: Give a try of my answer and let me know feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX(products!A:A,MATCH(C2,products!C:C,0))
```

With ***Microsoft-365*** can try-

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,products!C:C,products!A:A,"")
```

[image]